# Use Firebase in Web App via Phone Number Log in to Restrict Access to Site?

Tags: firebase, web, mobile, firebase-authentication

Firebase now provides an authentication method using the users phone.  A user opens a web page, and the page initiates a SMS verification process. 
 Firebase stores the users phone number (Identifier) and a randomly generated User UID. This is great if you want to validate phone numbers of your users, but not so great for restricting access to a whitelist of known phone numbers.  Using [Firebase phone auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth) and the very handy [firebaseui-web library](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web) you receive an authorization when a phone number (ANY phone number) is validated via SMS message.

I guess I could perform a test in the browser client to see if the phone number (after SMS validation) is on the authorized whitelist via an API call to another server; If valid team member, redirect to the team directory site and to a "thanks anyway" site if not.  I will say, performing that query in the client browser JavaScript seems like the wrong thing to do.  It would be too easy to cheat it. Definitely not a good thing to do,

I'm hoping to use Firebase and phone SMS authorization to restrict a web page's access to a white list of authorized phone numbers. My use case is a group of people who need access to a simple web page showing the phone numbers of others in the group.  We don't want that visible to the world, but it would be nice to have in a handy form (i.e.  Look up web page, press the `<a href="tel:1-408-555-5555">1-408-555-5555</a>` phone number for quick, easy access on a mobile phone.  We intend to make the page persistent via Progressive Web Application methods.

Any hints on how to proceed on using Firebase to restrict a webpage to a whitelist of users' phone numbers?

Note: I've seen [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27212004/can-firebase-hosting-restrict-access-to-resources) that hints that it may be possible to use Cloud Function to restrict access to content but its not clear to me how that would work.

(edit) Hmmm...  Maybe I'm overthinking this.  I could use a node.js server as the host with a `res.redirect('SuccessPhoneList.html')`to handle an Ajax call back to the server. That would fix my client Javascript redirect issue.  I can make that work, but sure would like Firebase to handle this without the extra Ajax call.

Comment: Consider using a combination of custom user claims and Firebase rules (or your own custom claims verification within the ID token) to enforce this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way in Firebase Hosting to restrict access to files, and no way in Firebase Authentication to limit who can create an account.

Typically this use-case is solved by:

1. Storing the list of phone numbers in a database, such as the [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/), or [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/).
2. Limit access to that data to users whose phone number is in your whitelist, with [Firebase's server-side security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security).

Also see these related questions:

- [Can Firebase hosting restrict access to resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27212004/can-firebase-hosting-restrict-access-to-resources)
- [How to prevent other access to my firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18005984/how-to-prevent-other-access-to-my-firebase)
- [Firebase Hosting: Preventing unauthorized access to URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47837517/firebase-hosting-preventing-unauthorized-access-to-url)