# Firebase hosting allow access to only minified js/css

Tags: firebase, web-hosting, firebase-hosting

We have a public directory in Firebase project, in which we have js, css, and img directory.

The public/js and public/css directory contains file.js and file.min.js as well.

**What I want --**

How do we restrict user to allow access to public/js/*.min.js and public/css/*.min.css ONLY.

That is minified files only.

**What I don't want --**

The user could not access .js and .css files directly, even if the address is known like https://***AnyFirebaseDomain.com/js/file.js

The one can not access above URL, even not any .js and .css hosted over serve.

That is restrict non-minified files to access from browser.

Comment: @Doug Stevenson this question is different from the question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47837517/firebase-hosting-preventing-unauthorized-access-to-url) 
Yes your answer to the question is seems to be the answer for this question. Please read carefully both the questions, that question is for <Preventing unauthorized access to URL>

Comment: There is no way to control access to files in Firebase Hosting based on whether the user is authenticated or not.